# RESTful services and mixed data response

Tags: web-services, rest, url, url-routing, restful-url

There is a server and the client. The client needs to get the list of shops and discounts in those shops from the server.

I have 2 ways:

1. At first I get all shops
   e.q. `GET http://myservice.com/shops`
   Then I get discounts in those shops
   e.q. `GET http://myservice.com/shops/discounts`
    
   *(two requests)*
2. To get all in one (shops & discounts)
    e.q. `GET http://myservice.com/shops_and_discounts`
   *(one request)*

**Whether the second decision contradicts the principles of RESTful services?

Or it is better to use the first way?**
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST emphasizes an uniform interface between components, and it's one of its advantages when it drives you towards implementing more general solutions to your problems. There's nothing inherently wrong with either approach, but you're creating a special case that isn't obvious at first sight and needs explicit documentation.

The solution I use for that problem is something I call the zoom protocol. Ideally, option 1 should be enough, and if clients have to make two requests, so be it. However, you might have even other resources nested even deeper, and either solution -- multiple requests or aggregating resources explicity -- won't scale very well.

The idea is to have a `zoom` numeric parameter that includes the related children resources in the parent's representation, for as many levels as needed. For instance, `/shops` returns all shops. `/shops?zoom=1` returns all shops with all discounts and any other immediate children resources embedded. `/shops?zoom=2` would do the same and apply `zoom=1` to the children resources themselves, embedding the immediate children of discounts, and so on.

The advantage of this method is that you can make it standard and clients can use it accross your API wherever they need it.